# program to count commented characters and words in a C file

Tags: c, count, character

I have to count characters and word in comment of a C file, for both single line comments and blocked comment. Here's what I have:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

#define IN = 1
#define OUT = 0

main() {
    int c, nc;
    nc = 0;
    while ((c = getchar()) != EOF) {
        if (c == '/') {
            if (getchar() == '/')
                while (getchar() != '\n')
                    ++nc;
        }  
    }
    
    if (c == '/') {
        if (getchar() == '*')
            while (getchar() != '/')
                ++nc;
    }  
    
    printf("Character Counts: %d\n", nc);
}
```

It works for every single line comment (`//`), but it skips the blocked comments (`/*...*/`). I feel like it never enter the if block for the blocked comment. Much appreciate!

Comment: Shouldn't `while (getchar() != '/')` be `while (getchar() != '*')`?

Comment: That's what I thought, but that if block never get entered

Answer (score 2):

There are multiple problems in your code:

- You must specify `int` as the return type of the `main` function. The syntax in the question is obsolete.
- The definitions of `IN` and `OUT` are incorrect. You should either use

  ```
    #define IN   1
    #define OUT  0
  ```

  or

  ```
    enum { IN = 1, OUT = 0 };
  ```
- The first loop consumes all the bytes in standard input, you are at the end of file, so the tests for `/*...*/` comments never produce anything.
- loops such as `while (getchar() != '\n')` can run forever if the byte tested is not found before the end of file.
- You cannot test `//` and `/*...*/` comments separately as one can hide the other:

  ```
    //* this is a line comment that does not start a C style one

    /* this comment contains a // but stops here */ return 0;
  ```
- Note also that you should parse C strings and character constants as they may contain `//` and or `/*` sequences that do not start a comment.
- For a complete solution, you should also handle escaped newlines. Here are some pathological examples:

  ```
    // this is a line comment that extends \
       on multiple \
       lines (and tricks the colorizer)

    /\
    * this is a C comment, but the colorizer missed it *\
    /
  ```

This problem is non-trivial to solve in the general case, but you can start with simple cases.

Here is a modified version:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int c, cc, nc = 0;

    while ((c = getchar()) != EOF) {
        if (c == '/') {
            if ((cc = getchar()) == '/') {
                while ((c = getchar()) != '\n')
                    nc++;
            } else
            if (cc == '*') {
                while ((cc = getchar()) != EOF) {
                    if (cc == '*') {
                        if ((cc = getchar()) == '/')
                            break;
                        ungetc(cc, stdin);
                    }
                    nc++;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    printf("Character Counts: %d\n", nc);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: @user3121023: [GCC does not complain for me.](https://godbolt.org/z/o1cjn7) What switches are you using? Be aware that GCC is not always a C compiler; various combinations of switches can set it to behave in ways that do not conform to the C standard.

Comment: Thanks for your elaboration. I forgot to mention that the comments are assumed to be entered correctly.

Comment: @SanLuong: Those aberrant looking comments are 'correct' but unorthodox and confusing.  The code shown doesn't attempt to deal with backslash-newline issues affecting comments.  Trigraphs could, in theory, have an impact too, though C++ has decided to eliminate them — `??/` is the trigraph for backslash, and could affect continuation lines.

Comment: @chqrlie, relly appreciate your help. Would the ungetc(cc, stdin) put the character cc just read back in the input stream?

Comment: @SanLuong — yes; the ”ungotten” character will be returned by the next call to `getchar()`.

Answer (score 0):

I added code to count the words. It works on few occasions, but it behaves weird when I have space after the slash. For example, // comment... Most of the time, the word count is off by 1.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#define IN 1
#define OUT 0

int main() {
    int c, cc, nc = 0;
    int state;
    int nw = 0;
    state = OUT;
    
    while ((c = getchar()) != EOF) {
        if (c == '/') {
            if ((cc = getchar()) == '/') {
                while ((c = getchar()) != '\n'){
                  nc++;
                  if (c == ' ' || c == '\t')
                      state = OUT;
                   else if (state == OUT){
                      state = IN;
                      nw++;
                    }        
                }
            }      
       
            else if (cc == '*') {
                while ((cc = getchar()) != EOF) {
                if (cc == ' ' || cc == '\t')
                      state = OUT;
                   else if (state == OUT){
                      state = IN;
                      nw++;
                    }
                
                    if (cc == '*') {
                        if ((cc = getchar()) == '/')
                            break;
                        ungetc(cc, stdin);
                    }

                    nc++;
                }
            }
        }
    }
     
    printf("Character Counts: %d\n", nc);
    printf("Word Counts: %d\n", nw);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> program to count commented characters and words in a C file

> it skips the blocked comments (/*...*/)

I recommend, at a minimum, to parse code and look for 5 states: normal, in a // comment, in a /* comment, in a "" string literal, in a '' character constant.

```
// pseudo code
while ((ch = getchar()) != EOF) {
   if ch == '/' and next == '/', process `//` comment until end-of-line
   elseif ch '/' and next == '*', process `/*` comment until `*/`
   elseif ch '"', process string until  " (but not \")
   elseif ch ''', process constant until  ' (but not \')
   else process normally
}
```

To look at the *next* character, call `getchar()` and then `ungetc()` if not as expected.